# Why ${^\perp}(F^\perp)$ is separable in this proof? (I couldn't find the countable set.)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

[image]
[image]
In this proof line -3: "${^\perp}(F^\perp)$ is closed linear span of $F$ and this subspace of $X$ is separable." I know ${^\perp}(F^\perp)=\overline{\operatorname{span}(F)}$, but we only know $F$ is countable. How to show $span(F)$ is countable to satisfy ${^\perp}(F^\perp)$ is separable?

Here is some definitions:
If $A\subseteq X$, then we denote $$A^{\perp}=\{x^*\in X^*:\langle a,x^*\rangle=0 \textrm{ for all }a\in A\}.$$ 
    Similarly, if $B\subseteq X^*$, then we denote $$^{\perp}B=\{x\in X:\langle x,b^*\rangle=0 \textrm{ for all }b^*\in B\}.$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear span of a countable set $F$ is separable : pick a countable dense set $D \subseteq \mathbb{F}$, say $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q} + i\mathbb{Q}$ depending on whether the field of reals or complex numbers is used, and then the set

$$\{ \sum_{i=1}^n q_i \cdot x_i: n \in \mathbb{N} ,\forall_{1\le i \le n}: q_i \in D, x_i \in F\}$$

is countable (a union of images of the countable sets $\mathbb{Q}^n \times F^n$ over all finite $n$) and dense in $\operatorname{span}(F)$. And if $\operatorname{span}(F)$ is separable, so is its closure, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you be more specific why the set $$\{ \sum_{i=1}^n q_i \cdot x_i: n \in \mathbb{N} ,\forall_{1\le i \le n}: q_i \in D, x_i \in F\}$$ is dense and countable?

Comment: I had a small argument about why its countable (as a countable union of countable sets) and we can approximate a term $r\cdot x$ ($r \in \mathbb{F})$ by a sequence $q_i \cdot x$ (from our countable set above) where the $q_i \to r$ are from $D$, which is dense, by continuity of scalar multiplication. We can do this for each of the finitely many terms in an element of the span of $F$.

Comment: I am sorry. I just begin to learn analysis by myself I don't quite understand (a union of images of the countable sets $\mathbb{Q}^n \times F^n$ over all finite $n$) to get the set you give is countable. Can you give me more details? Appreciate!!

Comment: @AnswerLee What do you know about countable sets?

Comment: @ HennoBrandsma A finite set or an infinite set with the same cardinality with $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $D$ is countable then $D^n$ (where $n \in \mathbb{N}$) is countable is known to you?

Comment: Yes and I know $\mathbb{Q}^n\times F^n$ is countable. But how to get the set you give is countable?

Comment: @AnswerLee For every fixed $n$ the set $S_n= \{\sum_{i=1}^n q_i\cdot x_i: q_i \in D, x_i \in F\}$ is countable as the image of $D^n \times F^n$ under the function $(q_1 ,\ldots q_n, x_1, \ldots x_n) \to \sum_{i=1}^n q_i\cdot x_i$. A function image of a countable set is also countable. And then our set is just $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} S_n$ which is also countable when all $S_n$ are.

Comment: Nice!! Get it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @AnswerLee Glad I could help!